# How PHP5.2.17 get service status on Win7

Tags: php, windows-7

I moved a PHP website from `win2003sp2 Standard` to `win7 Enterprise`. Nothing changed. The website works correct in win2003. But in win7 when get service status via `win32_query_service_status()`, return `WIN32_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I can not figure it out.

---

As link provided by Dan, I know Win2003 is different from later Windows for remote authenticated users. Is it the root cause that I cannot get the service status via my website page?

### Quote: `Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  Remote authenticated users are granted the SC_MANAGER_CONNECT, SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE, SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS, and STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ access rights. These access rights are restricted as described in the previous table as of Windows Server 2003 with SP1`

The access right are restricted as of `win2003sp1`. But the Website works correct on `win2003sp2`. I think it may be not the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, change the authentication of the folder where `win32_query_service_status()` located as below solved my problem.

> 1. Anonymous Authentication - Disabled
> 2. Windows Authentication - Enabled

Answer (score 1):

The user that PHP is running as does not have the correct rights to the SCM database.  See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The access right are restricted as of win2003sp1. But the Website works correct on win2003sp2. I think it may be not the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

`WIN32_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`  error is `"The handle to the SCM database does not have the appropriate access rights"` mentioned on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/win32service.constants.errors.php).

check current user permission to folder that may be help ..